# Is it possible to use register to assign the file source dynamically in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm new to Ansible. Recently, I need ansible to do this --

1. execute a command on client to get this client's role name
2. copy a file to this client by that client's role name--
   eg.
   client's name can be -- "web1", "db1", "cache2" ... This can be get by run an app -- "/opt/userlib/getrolename"
   And the file name would be "web1.conf", "db1.conf", "cache2.conf" ...

So I'm trying this --

```
- name: conf_files
  hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: tracing
      shell: |
        date +%F_%T >> /tmp/ansible_record.log

    - name: get host role
      shell: |
        /opt/userlib/getrolename|sed "s/rolename://"
      register: host_output

    - name: check output
      debug:
        msg: "{{host_output.stdout}}"

    - name: copy file with number
      copy:
        src: {{ host_output.stdout }}.txt
        dest: /tmp/reg_role.txt
```

From the debug output, it looks good -- that I can get the role by register's stdout. But it failed by dynamic file source name-- {{ host_output.stdout }}.txt

```
The offending line appears to be:

      copy:
        src: {{ host_output.stdout }}.txt
                                     ^ here
```

Would you please tell me is it possbile to use dynamic file source name with variable in ansible? And if yes, how to use it?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you try quote it e.g. `"{{ host_output.stdout }}.txt"`?

Comment: Please read https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas => Quotes are mandatory when your jinja2 string starts with a double curly brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to use "double quotes" i.e `"{{ host_output.stdout }}.txt"`

See also [YAML Syntax (Gotchas)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas)

> Ansible uses “{{ var }}” for variables. If a value after a colon starts with a “{”, YAML will think it is a dictionary, so you must quote it

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm new to Ansible. and need more learning... :)

Comment: The documentation of Ansible is quite comprehensive, so you might find most information in there